# How to make two pictures not visible after a certain time

Tags: c#, audio, task, thread-sleep, pause

I'm making a memotest and I need to press two different images and they need to keep visible for 3-5 seconds. I've tried `Thread.Sleep(5000)` but it doesn't show me the second one. What should I do?
The only way I've founded to see for some seconds the images was by putting a `MessageBox` but that isn't the idea and I don't know other way to do it.

```
if (pic != null && pic.Name == fondos[i].Name)
{
    if (CantClick == 0)
    {
        ParejaActual = listRandom[i].pareja;
        CantClick = 1;
        primerI = i;
        picAnterior = pic;
        imgAnterior = img;
        pic.Visible = false;

    }
    else if (CantClick == 1)
    {
        pic.Visible = false;
        if (ParejaActual == listRandom[i].pareja)
        {
            SoundPlayer simpleSound = (new SoundPlayer(Configuracion.RootFolder + "aplau.wav"));
            simpleSound.Play();
            Ganando++;
            label3.Text = Ganando.ToString();
            //MessageBox.Show("Si");
            //NO SE DESTAPA LA SEGUNDA.
            //Thread.Sleep(5000);
            CantClick = 0;
            img.Visible = false;
            imgAnterior.Visible = false;
            Application.DoEvents();

        }
        else
        {

            (new SoundPlayer(Configuracion.RootFolder + "sad.wav")).Play();
            MessageBox.Show("No");
            Mal++;
            CantClick = 0;
            label4.Text = Mal.ToString();
            pic.Visible = true;
            picAnterior.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: You need to use a System.Windows.Forms.Timer object on your form. Don't _ever_ use Thread.Sleep in UI code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using Thread.Sleep , use [System.Timers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) class. After an interval, just hide one image and show the other. Tell me if you want any other help.

Comment: I can't show again the "pic" in a timer_tick because is a non public variable. How can I do?  private void timer3_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter3--;
            if (counter3 == 0)
            {
                CantClick = 0;
                picAnterior.Visible = true;
                picAnterior.Visible = true;
                Application.DoEvents();
                counter3 = 3;
                timer3.Stop();
            }
        }